# Joining to top query row column inside subquery

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm getting "multipart identifier TT.CreatedOnUTC could not be bound" error on WHERE part inside subquery. Not sure why? What is the proper way to fix this query?

```
UPDATE TT
    SET PreviouslyDeductedAmount = DrA.AdvancedAmount
    FROM #temp TT
        INNER JOIN
        (SELECT cRefNumber ReferenceId, SUM(nCashAmount) AdvancedAmount
        FROM prodsp.dbo.DriverAdvance (NOLOCK) DA
        WHERE da.dDate >= TT.CreatedOnUTC
        GROUP BY DA.cRefNumber) DrA ON TT.ComdataReferenceId = DrA.ReferenceId
```

Basically in #temp TT I have row, I want to find total of all "advances" joining by reference number and I need to make sure those advances happened AFTER date in my TT table, hence WHERE...

It works fine without WHERE, I tried to use #temp instead of TT but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use APPLY operator. Like this

```
UPDATE  TT
SET     PreviouslyDeductedAmount = DrA.AdvancedAmount
FROM    #temp TT
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT cRefNumber ReferenceId ,
                            SUM(nCashAmount) AdvancedAmount
                     FROM   prodsp.dbo.DriverAdvance (NOLOCK) DA
                     WHERE  da.dDate >= TT.CreatedOnUTC AND TT.ComdataReferenceId = DrA.ReferenceId
                     GROUP BY DA.cRefNumber
                   ) DrA
```